# iPhone - iPad Device Type Trick in the Header File

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, header

So I've got a function that really helps when I'm crafting device specific URLS but I'd like to place it in a global header file so any class could use it easily

```
- (NSString *)deviceType
{
    NSString *deviceName = @"iphone";
    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    {
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
            deviceName = @"ipad";
        }
        else {
            deviceName = @"iphone4";
        }
    }
    return deviceName;
}
```

That may or may not be the best way of doing it but I'd like to know how to get that into a global header so I can do something like this

```
NSString *deviceName = GETDEVICENAME;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer that worked for me,

In a global header file Globals.h I placed

```
NSString* deviceType();
```

in Globals.m I placed a modified function

```
NSString* deviceType()
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        return @"ipad";
    }
    else if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    {
        return @"iphone4";
    }
    else{
        return @"iphone";

    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear this really does what you wan't.  I think a 3GS iPhone running iOS 4.0 will show up as an iPhone4.  You probably want to check respondsToSelector AND [UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as stated above. The scale property of UIScreen was introduced in iOS4.0. So any device running iOS4.0+ (ipod, iphone, iwhatever) will respond as iphone4 with the above code. I think generally to pinpoint the exact model someone is using is wrong way to turn design wise. Code like this is subject to break down the road.

Check out the documents of UIScreen's scale property
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/scale

Answer (score 0):

`#define GETDEVICENAME [whatever deviceType]` maybe?

There is an issue with your function though, on 3.2 UIScreen doesn't respond to scale (at least no publicly. I wouldn't rely on that to check for iPad.

Comment: so cut out the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM from the if statement right? Logic is still sound if I return early

Answer (score 0):

With in your project should be a file called %PROJECT%_Prefix.pch.

Any headers you include in that file will be accessible by all files in your project.

Comment: I've got a Global header up and running but need help on the function